# What are different between NSUTF8StringEncoding and NSUTF16StringEncoding?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, nsarray, nsutf8encoding

I am trying to understand about Encoding, as far i know utf-8 encode mean it t uses 8-bit blocks to represent a character.

```
NSString *NSUTF8Encoding = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:"String" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *NSUTF16Encoding = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:"String" encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"NSUTF8StringEncoding :%@",NSUTF8Encoding);

NSLog(@"NSUTF16StringEncoding :%@",NSUTF16Encoding);
```

its say :
**Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future**

what does it mean?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [unicode.org: General questions, relating to UTF or Encoding Form](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)

Answer (score -1):

- `NSUTF8StringEncoding` : An 8-bit representation of Unicode characters.
- `NSUTF16StringEncoding` : An 16-bit representation of Unicode characters.

It relates to the amount of possible letters/numbers/symbols a character set can have. An 8-Bit character can only have 256 possible characters. Whereas a 16-bit can have 65,536.

Comment: So what is the very incorrect about it? Don't just vote down, explain why?

Comment: Basically everything. You don't know what `UTF8` is because you are mixing it up with ASCII. Both `UTF8` and `UTF16` can encode the entire Unicode character set, which is about 1,112,064 characters. That's because  they are *variable-length encodings*. The 8 and 16 is not the number of bits per character.

Comment: @Sulthan what exactly mean of encoding?